# Parallel line with a known point

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

Line *m* goes through a point D(2, -4). Line *m* is parallel to line *l:* $5x+3y=-17$. Describe line *m* with an equation of type $ax+by=c$.

The solution should be $c=5*2+3*-4=-2$ so $\text{m: }5x+3y=-2$

The lines are parallel so $a=5$, $x$ and $y$ are known so: $5*2+b(-4)=c$. At this point I lack some information I should know to push that equation further. I suppose I should be able to fill either $b$ or $c$, but which one and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knowing that they're parallel tells you that they share the same gradient.
Try solving it like this and see if you can follow the method;

Rearranging line l into the standard form y = mx + c should show you that the gradient (m) of both lines (since they're parallel) is -(5/3)

Then you have that the equation of line m is;

y = -(5/3)x + c

Substitute in point D(2 , -4) to get c;

-4 = -(5/3)*2 + c

c = -4 + 10/3

c = -2/3

So putting everything into an equation for m, we have;

y = -(5/3)x -2/3

Just rearrange for the form asked for in the question;

(5/3)x + y = -2/3

Or in a little bit nicer form;

5x + 3y = -2